# Debugging Varnish's hit_for_pass objects

Tags: php, caching, varnish

I am new to Varnish and I am struggling to see why so many requests are either a `miss`, or `hit_for_pass`.

I have added `unset req.http.Cookie;` inside `vcl_recv` to (if I am right) effectively ignore all cookies and cache regardless of cookies? Is this right?

But despite this I am still getting no `hits`. So this cookie approach is either wrong or there is an entirely different reason why this is not working.

Any ideas on this, or is there a way to see exactly why I am getting `hit_for_pass` or `miss` so often.

Thanks
Jake

**EDIT**

Some more Googling and I found this

```
sub vcl_fetch {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie; 
}
```

So I guess this removes the cookie from the response object, can someone explain why this now works and what it is I have done to get it working?

**EDIT2**

A second look at `varnishstat` shows this isn't working as I expected and I am still getting many many misses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are, if you're getting a lot of `hit_for_pass` decisions, you've also got very little in the cache itself, hence the misses.

`hit_for_pass` is only thrown from the `vcl_fetch` method, I believe, so it is worth looking at what your server is returning. Things to consider include:

- `remove beresp.http.Cache-Control;` and `remove beresp.http.Pragma;`
  to stop your backend applications from blocking caching.
- `remove beresp.http.Expires;` to avoid now/past expiry dates (you may wish to change this to a far-future expires depending on what you're serving).
- If your app is not serving cookies, then `remove beresp.http.Set-Cookie;` will have a big impact on your hit_for_pass rates.
- Make sure you are setting an appropriate `beresp.ttl` value.

I'd also recommend that you read [this article about the 'Accept-Encoding' header](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression#Ithoughtyousaidthiswascomplicated) (the code in the example goes in the `vcl_recv` method).

Comment: Thanks Dan. This has helped & I am now getting hits. I really want to understand why this has worked. Removing `Cache-Control` & `Pragma` makes sense, as Varnish is now doing the caching and the backend's cache headers should be ignored. Expires, is this used by Varnish, e.g. if it's in the past does this affect Varnish or if it is next week will Varnish ignore it's ttl setting and use the Expires header instead? Finally removing Set Cookie makes sense, I just need ifs for my `/admin` section

Comment: A new 'finally' here Cache-Control is used (https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/increasing_your_hitrate.html#cache-control), should I be in fact using my backend to set Cache-Control headers, maybe in the .htaccess file and relying on these for Varnish to use rather than writing a new complex VCL?

Answer (score 1):

For others who may have this issue, this was useful.

https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleHitMissHeader

Setting headers to show what is and is not cached and why.